# Eject USB Device (no disk) on MAC osx

Tags: macos, usb

I want to access an usb device from my nodejs application. Unfortunately it seems like my MAC already claimed the usb device, which leads to failures in the library I use.

I can see the usb device with `system_profiler SPUSBDataType`. The device is a coin acceptor so **it is not a disk, thus not removable with `diskutil`**.

```
    CCT 900:

      Product ID: 0x6001
      Vendor ID: 0x0403  (Future Technology Devices International Limited)
      Version: 6.00
      Serial Number: whCCT0344456
      Speed: Up to 12 Mb/sec
      Manufacturer: wh Berlin
      Location ID: 0x14200000 / 13
      Current Available (mA): 1000
      Current Required (mA): 100
      Extra Operating Current (mA): 0
```

Answer (score 0):

You might want to try the `umount` command.

See [here](https://developer.apple.com/legacy/library/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man8/umount.8.html).